# How to configure Non-authenticated push notification for windows phone 8 in worklight

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have configured push notification in Android and IOS, and it's works perfectly. but when I configured Non-authenticated push notification for windows phone 8 in worklight, it's not working.I follow the below MobileFirst document to run push notification for windows Phone 8:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupWP8

Also i want to know, for subscription based push notification, which notification is recommended for windows phone 8 i.e. Non-authenticated push or Authenticated push?

Below is my code:

adapter.js

```
function submitNotification(userId, notificationText){
var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

if (userSubscription==null){
    return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
}
var notification={};
notification.MPNS={};
var badgeDigit = 1;

var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
notification.MPNS.toast={};
notification.MPNS.toast.text1 = "Toast title";
notification.MPNS.toast.text2 = "Toast content";
WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);

WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);


return { 
    result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId 
};
}
```

application-descriptor.xml

```
<windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
    <uuid>5747-54938-fjhg-f459-844h-fhkj</uuid>
</windowsPhone8>
```

Please help me on windows phone 8 push notification.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**Update Question**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
After adding push sender id in "application-descriptor.xml". push notification is working on windows phone8. but facing problem to receive broadcast notification on windows phone8.

**broadcastAdapter**.js

```
function sendBroadcastNotification(applicationId, notificationText) { 
var notificationOptions = {}; 
notificationOptions.message = {}; 
notificationOptions.message.alert = notificationText; 
WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions); 
return { 
result : "Notification sent to all users." 
 }; 
}
```

client side code in **main.js**:

```
if(WL.Client.Push){ 
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) { 
navigationFromNotification = true; 
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Provider notification data: " +    JSON.stringify(props), [ { 
text : 'Close', 
handler : function() { 
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Brodcast Notifications", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ { 
text : 'Close', 
handler : function() { 
window.location.href="#/home/2"; 
 } 
}]); 
 } 
}]); 
}; 
}
```

**Am I need to add anything to receive broadcast Notification on windows phone8** **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you have linked to clearly mentions to add an empty `pushSender` element, and as can be seen in your code snippet from application-descriptor.xml - you did not do that. Basically, you did not configure your application to use push notifications(!).

```
<windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
    <uuid>auto-generated by the platform</uuid>
    <pushSender /> 
</windowsPhone8>
```

Authenticated or not authenticated push is not related to user-based subscription.
You can use either one. The only limitation by MS is that non-authenticated is limited to 500 messages per day, whereas authenticated is not limited (and more secure).

Comment: Yes that uuid is auto generated only.

Comment: but still not working. Also i asked for subscription based push notification, which notification is recommended i.e. Non-authenticated push or Authenticated push?
please clear this two questions.

Comment: "Still not working" is not an answer. Provide a real answer explaining what is not working. Logs, error messages.

Comment: i'll explain you, Whatever i did till now:
1. Create windows phone 8 environment.
2. Write Notification code in adapter.js as mention above in question.
3.In application-descriptor.xml, mention uuid (which is auto-generated).

Comment: If you did not add the push sender element it will not work. Add it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i added <pushSender/>  i am geeting below error Notification through Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) to subscription 'http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/xxxx' was not delivered (reason: 'Connect to s.notify.live.net:80 [s.notify.live.net/40.76.17.107] failed: Connection refused: connect'). Is there any Network issue ???

Comment: Yes, looks like you have a network issue. You need to talk with your IT/network administrator.

Comment: thanks for your help. I discussed with IT/network administrator and now subscription based is working fine.

Comment: hey! can you help me out to receive broadcast notification on windows phone 8? same broadcast code is working for android and ios but not for windows phone 8. am I need to configure any thing for windows phone 8 for broadcast notification?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94203/discussion-between-priyank-and-idan-adar).

Comment: see my updated question with code, I am facing problem to send broadcast notification to Windows phone8.

Answer (score 1):

a) MPNS Push notifications can operate in unauthenticated or authenticated mode. In unauthenticated mode, the number and frequency of notifications allowed through the Microsoft Push Notification Service is throttled (unauthenticated push notifications are currently limited to 500 per day, per channel).

MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx).

IBM MobileFirst supports both authenticated and non-authenticated MPNS push.

b) In case of Tag/Broadcast MPNS notifications, by default the notification appears within the application tile. For the notification to be displayed when the application is in foreground or as a toast notification add the following code to the sendBroadcastNotification() method in the adapter:

```
notificationOptions.settings = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns ={};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.raw = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.raw.payload= {'payload' : notificationText};

notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast ={};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text1 = 'Title';
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text2= notificationText;
```

Refer to the TagNotifications sample for the complete [code](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/)

Comment: Thanks, But this thing I know already. but my problem is i'm not getting any push notification after configuration uuid in "application-descriptor.xml"  and notification code in "adapter.js". please help me on this :)

Comment: hey! can you help me out to receive broadcast notification on windows phone 8? same broadcast code is working for android and ios but not for windows phone 8. am I need to configure any thing for windows phone 8 for broadcast notification?

Comment: a) If you do not add <pushSender> tag to the application-descriptor for Windows Phone 8 , you will not receive push notifications
b) Edit the question or provide details on the broadcast notification code that is working on Android / iOS but not on WP8.

Comment: see my updated question with code, I am facing problem to send broadcast notification to Windows phone8

Comment: Looks like you have not seen my earlier comments in the chat. 

Move the WL.Client.Push.onMessage=function(props,payload) {...} ,outside of any function declaration or checks? Let it be on its own. 
Also , note that "window.location.href" way of navigating away from the current page is not supported in MFP. MFP follows single DOM model and navigating away using href is not supported

Comment: I tried but not working. I don't know why but the same code is working for android and IOS.